# doctrine criteria same field with different value

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
$columnName = "date";
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->andWhere($criteria->expr()->gte($columnName, $startDate));
$criteria->andWhere($criteria-expr()->lte($columnName, $endDate));
```

This will cause "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"
It will generate SQL like this

```
...AND (table.date >= :date AND table.date <= :date)
```

how do I fix it? It seems like eventhough it has the correct parameter, the name of the field in sql is the same

Comment: very strange.. try this approach:  $expr = Criteria::expr();
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(
      $expr->andX(
        $expr->gte('start', $start),
        $expr->lte('end', $end)
      )
    );

Comment: Are you sure the error messages is caused by the criteria?